# Matching and factoring across data frames in R without For loop

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop

I have two data frames, one of survey response options (levels) and one of the coded responses.  Across data frames, the columns have the same names but not necessarily the same order.  Also, within the levels data frame, questions may have different numbers of response options.

```
levels <- data.frame(restaurant=c("TACO BELL","CHIPOTLE",""),
                     would_recommend=c("YES","NO",""),
                     satisfaction=c("VERY SATISFIED","SATISFIED","UNSATISFIED"))                  

responses <- data.frame(satisfaction=c(2,2,1,1,3,3,2,2),
                        would_recommend=c(1,2,1,1,2,2,2,1),
                        restaurant=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2))
```

The responses are essentially factors whose levels are the same-named column in the levels table, so I would like to convert them to factors.

I know that I can do this by:

```
for (i in 1:length(responses)){
  resp_levels <- levels[,match(names(responses)[i],names(levels))]
  responses[,i]<-factor(x=resp_levels[responses[,i]],levels=resp_levels)
}
```

Is there a clever way to do this without a For loop?

Comment: Please, do not be afraid of a for loop here. Your solution is clever enough, IMHO. Such a task won't definitely be a bottleneck in your code, unless you evaluate it thousands of times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally agree with @gogolews that there is nothing wrong with a for loop if it works for you, and especially a simple one like yours. However, if you really want a non-loop solution, here is one with the packages `tidyr` and `dplyr`. This may be faster on a really gigantic data-set, but its hard to say for sure:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

First, gather responses into a long format data.frame, and add an id variable so that we know which go together later.  We convert the factor to a character so we can index it by name later

```
new_responses <- responses %>% mutate(id = row_number(restaurant)) %>% 
gather(question,  response, -id) %>% mutate(question = as.character(question))
```

Now use dplyr to grab the appropriate level from levels data.frame then spread this back out to short form using tidyr and delete no longer needed id.

```
responses2 <- new_responses %>% rowwise %>% 
mutate(response = as.character(levels[response, question])) %>% 
spread(question, response) %>% select(-id)
responses2

Source: local data frame [8 x 3]

  restaurant   satisfaction would_recommend
1  TACO BELL      SATISFIED             YES
2  TACO BELL VERY SATISFIED             YES
3  TACO BELL    UNSATISFIED              NO
4  TACO BELL      SATISFIED              NO
5   CHIPOTLE      SATISFIED              NO
6   CHIPOTLE VERY SATISFIED             YES
7   CHIPOTLE    UNSATISFIED              NO
8   CHIPOTLE      SATISFIED             YES
```

Note that the rows won't necessarily be in the same order as in the original, but it would be possible to do this by using the id variable to resort the new data.frame.